# Ethereum/Solidity dev here, looking to migrate some Solidity contracts onto Tezos. Was hoping to have some light shed on a few questions

Tags: michelson, liquidity, smartpy, ligo

Was hoping to have some light shed on a few questions.

Narrowing in on using Ligo, Archetype, or Liquidity.

1. Is Liquidity kind of a dead-end right now? I noticed it's not listed on developeres.tezos.com, and with the whole Dune thing....
   *(or is it in your best interest to use one of the others, if starting something new?)*
2. Do Archetype/Ligo provide everything that Michelson can currently do, or are there limitations with either?
3. In Solidity, you can inline assembly (for optimizations, unimplemented opcodes). Can you do something similar in Arche/Ligo?
4. How well is inheritance/cross contract communication supported in Archetype/Ligo?

Comment: Welcome, would be better if you split this up into multiple questions. For general discussion on these issues Agora/Riot/Reddit are better fits. For specific Q&A on this site, your first question on Liquidity will lead more to opinions so please consider restating it if you want a specific answer. The second question has already received an answer below and best candidate if you decide to edit the title of this post. The third one would be great for a new question.

Comment: Liquidity is not a supported language in tezos. On the other hand SmartPy should probably be in your list

Comment: @Ezy, we looked at Liquidity, along with all the others listed on developers.tezos.com, and began narrowing down to mainly Ligo/Archetype. SmartPy  i̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶o̶p̶e̶n̶-̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶y̶e̶t̶ https://medium.com/@SmartPy_io/new-release-for-smartpy-and-smartpy-io-89d11dc5146a ← Yay!, it's back on the list =)

Comment: @Ezy Liquidity states on their website that they support both Dune and Tezos. What makes it unsupported for Tezos?

Comment: @Justin ocamlpro who is the author of liquidity left the tezos project to follow their own path. It is not actively maintained to work with tezos so it is only a matter of time before it stops compiling on tezos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In response to question 4:

### Reuse and modularity

We discuss reuse and modularity, of which inheritance is one of many mechanisms:

- **Michelson** has no mechanism for code reuse, except for calling
  existing "library" contracts directly.
- As far as I understand, **Archetype** includes no user-extendable
  mechanisms for code reuse. Actions (akin to methods) cannot be
  shared between different state machines (akin to
  contracts). Furthermore, actions cannot not call each other, so
  cannot be composed. State machines cannot be extended or
  composed. Archetypes contracts are composed of one file. However,
  Archetype contains a set of extensions, that encapsulate commonly
  used patterns such as `signed`, which requires that one argument of
  an action should be the signature of another argument.
- **LIGO** contracts, irrespective of the syntax used, are composed of
  a set of functions. These functions can be reused, and are in
  general composable as one would expect from functions in any
  language, with exception of recursion. What's more, the Ligo compiler
  calls the [C preprocessor (`cpp`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) on input contracts, which
  enables a certain degree of reuse and composability through the use
  of `#include` directives. Morally, this is equivalent to
  copy-pasting the included file: there is no namespacing to save you
  from name clashes. Finally, the use of `cpp` is undocumented and
  subject to change, as testified to by this message by the following
  message on the [#ligo channel on the tezos-dev slack](https://tezos-dev.slack.com/archives/CFX0B8Q3X/p1578737934090000):

> Currently, LIGO is shipped with the C preprocessor cpp which acts as a
> poor man's module system a la C. There several reasons why we should
> get rid of it, both immediately and in the long term [...]

- Finally, **SmartPy** contracts, which are actually Python programs
  that use the SmartPy library to construct a contract, have access
  to all the Python features on the *meta-programming level* (in
  other words, the code that generates the contract). That is,
  modules, classes (with inheritance), functions, high-level
  functions, decorators and compositions.

### Inter-contract communication

- **Michelson** has no specific mechanisms to simplify inter-contract
  communication. Calls to other contracts must be crafted manually through the
  [`TRANSFER_TOKENS`](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#instr-TRANSFER_TOKENS) instruction. Callbacks must be encoded (again)
  manually using [continuation-passing style (CPS)](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/278/get-a-returned-value-when-calling-a-michelson-contract/281#281).
- The same holds for [**LIGO**](https://ligolang.org/docs/advanced/entrypoints-contracts/#cross-contract-calls)
  and [**SmartPy**](https://smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_interacting_with_the_blockchain).
- In the current version, **Archetype** has little support for inter-contract communication. As
  far a I can see, there is only the [`transfer`](https://docs.archetype-lang.org/archetype-language/action#currency-transfer) instruction, with which
  it is not possible to specify the argument nor the entry-point of
  the called contract (presumably, only contracts of type `unit` are
  supported targets). No specific helpers for coding CPS style. However, this is amended in future versions of Archetype, as indicated by [Benoit's answer below](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2001/1773).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a complement to Arvid's answer regarding **Archetype**:

**Reuse and modularity**

Indeed Archetype's [extensions](https://docs.archetype-lang.org/archetype-language/extensions) are reusable codes to add features to a contract. For example, using the '[transferable](https://docs.archetype-lang.org/extensions-1/transferable)' extension on a role adds to the contract the necessary actions (ie entry points) to transfer the role to another address.

For example, invoking the 'transferable' extension on an admin role:

```
variable admin[%transferable%] role := @tz1iawHeddgggn6P5r5jtq2wDRqcJVksGVSa
```

will generate the two entry points `assign_new_admin` and `confirm_new_admin`.

From a design perspective, we have tried to keep the contract in a single source file as much as possible, for ease of reading and trust-carrying purposes. 
Most of Ethereum's contracts, for example, are usually shattered in literally dozens of source files by inheritance mechanisms, and we thought it was the opposite as what a smart contract should look like.

Extensions are not available yet in the current version (0.1.12) but will be soon (they are a few pull requests away ...).

**Inter contract communication**

There is support for contract calling in Archetype. For example, the following Archetype contract calls a contract at address KT1RNB9PXsnp7KMkiMrWNMRzPjuefSWojBAm

```
archetype contract_caller

contract contract_called_sig {
   action set_value (n : int)
   action add_value (a : int, b : int)
}
variable c : contract_called_sig = @KT1RNB9PXsnp7KMkiMrWNMRzPjuefSWojBAm


action update_value(n : int) {
  effect {
    c.set_value(n)
  }
}

action add_one(n : int) {
  effect {
    c.add_value(n, 2)
  }
}
```

We see that the contract signature must be provided with the contract keyword and that the call to the contract is similar to invoking a method on an object.

This feature is available in the dev branch and will be available soon in the next release (0.1.13 typically in a couple of weeks).

Answer (score 5):

> Do Archetype/Ligo provide everything that Michelson can currently do, or are there limitations with either?

I think if something is possible in Michelson and not in Ligo, it is probably a bug worth reporting, the Ligo devs usually quickly answer these kinds of issues.

Archetype however is purposely not Turing complete and in particular you cannot do unbounded loops in Archetype (unbounded loops are supported by the LOOP and LOOP_LEFT).

Answer (score 4):

With respect to question 3, following @ezy remark, SmartPy has some inlining capabilities including with new opcodes as shown in the Inline Michelson template (of the new version, currently https://SmartPy.io/dev).

It's accessible here: https://smartpy.io/dev/index.html?template=inlineMichelson.py.

```
import smartpy_michelson as mi

...

    @sp.entry_point
    def concat(self, params):
        concat = mi.operator("CONCAT", [sp.TList(sp.TString)], [sp.TString])
        self.data.s = concat(["a", "b", "c"])

    @sp.entry_point
    def seq(self, params):
        self.data.value = abs(mi.seq([mi.ADD(), mi.MUL(), mi.DUP(), mi.MUL()], 15, 16, 17))
```